# How to add custom fields to product in product-list.tpl?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I made modification in ProductController (in assignPriceAndTax function):

```
$this->context->smarty->assign(array(
        [...]
        'test_var' => 'test'
    ));
```

and this works in product page. But I want to add this var in product-list.tpl and homefeatured.tpl. Where I find controller for this?

Answer (score 0):

1. `product-list.tpl` uses for "pack products" and in default theme you
   may see it included in file `themes/theme-name/product.tpl` and not
   assigned into controller, there you may see something like:

   `{include file="$tpl_dir./product-list.tpl" products=$packItems}`

   where this part `products=$packItems` it is passing variables in
   included template, so for getting 'test_var' into `product-list.tpl`
   you have to pass it there:

   `{include file="$tpl_dir./product-list.tpl" products=$packItems
   test_var=$test_var}`
2. From other side `homefeatured.tpl` assigned in "Home featured"
   module and you can add your var in `hookDisplayHome()` method into
       `modules/homefeatured/homefeatured.php` file.